# List first n rows in a dataframe that meet a condition

Tags: dataframe

Suppose that we have a dataframe with multiple columns. It is then sorted on a specific set of columns using sort_values.

```
df.sort_values(by=['Col1','Col2'],ascending={False,True},inplace=True)
```

Now, I want to filter all rows that match a certain criterion, but list only the first n rows that meet that criterion. This makes sense for my application because I have done the sorting above.

How do I do that?

Edit: I did not make this clear earlier: n is not known ahead of time. In fact, I want to make this list, and also find n that satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to resources and performance, alternatively that could be filtered, before selecting the first row from rows which ordered specifically.

```
df.where(<condition>).orderBy(desc("Col1"), "Col2").first()
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a new form of applying the condition that I had not seen before. However, the problem here is that n is unknown. I want to list the first n rows that satisfy the condition, and also find n in the process. The data is sorted, so there is a unique answer to that question.

Comment: You can try to use head(n) or limit(n) function, otherwise you can also manipulate row number which generated from window.partition function or additional custom row column that contains unique row number.

Comment: I stumbled upon nlargest: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html, which is very close to what I need.